# How can I use UTF-8(Vietnamese) in Equation environment

Tags: amsmath, unicode

I'm a Latex newbie. I've just studied it for 2-3 weeks. But I'm stuck at inserting Vietnamese (UTF-8) into equation field. How can I do that without font errors after the files is compiled?

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,vietnamese,12pt]{article}
\author{}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage[vietnamese,english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tgbonum}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,left=2cm,right=1cm,top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{textcase}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}

\setlength{\parindent}{1cm}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\date{}
\title{\textbf{Bitch}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
\section{B
ooom Thuốc lào is so ngọt}
%%content
\begin{equation}
  thí điểm equation
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

output:[image: error in output]

Answer (score 3):

You just need to do this `\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}`. You don't need `\usepackage[vietnamese,english]{babel}`and remove `vietnamese` in the line `\documentclass[a4paper,vietnamese,12pt]{article}`  If you want to write text in 
math environment, you type `\text{}`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\author{}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
%\usepackage[vietnamese,english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tgbonum}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,left=2cm,right=1cm,top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{textcase}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}

\setlength{\parindent}{1cm}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\date{}
\title{\textbf{Bitch}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
\section{Booom Thuốc lào is so ngọt}
%%content
\begin{equation}
   \text{thí điểm equation}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But it looks to me that the mentioned line `\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}` is in the MWE of OP.

Comment: I agree with albert, the OP already have the `vietname` package). But your answer is still correct as it is the `\text` command that does the trick. Use `\text{....}` to enter a textual comment (I assume this is a Vietnamese comment) into a displayed piece of math

Comment: @daleif maybe you should post an answer, or minhthien_2016 should correct his answer as now his answer points in the wrong direction.

Comment: @albert it would be the same as this answer, just with the edit that in the first line `\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}` is replaced by `\text{...}`

Answer (score 3):

If the document's main language is Vietnamese and also has English parts, use

```latex
\usepackage[main=vietnamese,english]{babel}
```

If the document is only in Vietnamese, you have two choices: either

```latex
\usepackage[vietnamese]{babel}
```

or

```latex
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
```

but not both together.

Anyway, in order to typeset text in math equation, you need `\text`.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[main=vietnamese,english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tgbonum}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,left=2cm,right=1cm,top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{textcase}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}

\setlength{\parindent}{1cm}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

\author{}
\title{Title}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Booom Thuốc lào is so ngọt}

\begin{equation}
  \text{thí điểm equation}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

or

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tgbonum}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,left=2cm,right=1cm,top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{textcase}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}

\setlength{\parindent}{1cm}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

\author{}
\title{Title}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Booom Thuốc lào is so ngọt}

\begin{equation}
  \text{thí điểm equation}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

The output is similar.

[image]